# Specified cast is not valid (double precision to int)

Tags: c#, casting

Here I need to cast to double precision to integer.

**Example**:

```
obj.DayDifference = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader["DateDiff"].ToString()) ?   
               (Int32)reader["DateDiff"] : 0;
```

**Type**:

- `DayDifference` of type `int`
- `DateDiff` of type `double precision` in the `database table`.

**Error**:

> Specified cast is not valid

Comment: What is the value of `reader["DateDiff"]` exactly? Debug and tell us.

Comment: @SonerGönül, The `DateDiff` consist `value` 200.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're doing is equivalent to:

```
object x = 32.5;
int y = (int) x;
```

You can't do that - when you unbox, you have to unbox to the actual type of the value<sup>1</sup>.

So you'd need:

```
object x = 32.5;
int y = (int) (double) x;
```

The cast to `double` unboxes, and the cast to `int` converts the `double` to an `int`. You can do the same in your code:

```
(Int32)(Double) reader["DateDiff"] : 0;
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Well, modulo a few things. The CLR allows you to unbox an `int` to a `uint` or to an enum type with an underlying type of `int`, etc.